# Find first positive integer $n$ (where $n$ not equals to $0$) for which $\cos n\theta = 1$?

Tags: trigonometry

Given 
$\cos\theta = \frac{p}{q}$
How to find first positive $n$ for which 
$\cos n\theta = 1$? Here p and q are integers

Comment: Are $p$ and $q$ supposed to be integers?

Comment: Yes p and q are integers

Comment: Then, write so in your question, please!

Comment: If $\cos\theta=1/3$, I don't think there is a positive integer $n$ such that $\cos n\theta=1$. So, $n$ doesn't have to be an integer?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson You're right, there are only very few integers $p,q$ where such an integer $n$ exists ($p/q$ must be $0,\pm1,\pm1/2$).